# Make a regular button look like slack

Tags: html, razor, slack

I have a button which when pressed revokes a user's access token. I want to make it look like the Sign in with Slack button.
I am attaching the html code for the Sign in with Slack Button below.

```html
<a href="https://slack.com/oauth/authorize?scope=identity.basic,identity.email,identity.team,identity.avatar&client_id=373568302675.374024189699">
  <img alt="Sign in with Slack" height="40" width="172" src="https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/sign_in_with_slack.png" srcset="https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/sign_in_with_slack.png 1x, https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/sign_in_with_slack@2x.png 2x"
  />
```

What do I need to do to make my button look the same?
For now, the code for my button is as under:

```html
<input type="button" value="Unlink Slack" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action(" RevokeAuth ","Settings ")'"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for I added the input to a div with the slack image and added the onclick to the div as well as the button so the pointer looks correct.

```html
<style>
  .slk {
    border: 1px solid #C8C8C8;
    width: 170px;
    width: 170px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: flex;
    height: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .slkInp {
    color: #383838;
    background-color: white;
    border: none;
    padding: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  
  .slkInp:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
</style>

<div class="slk" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action(" RevokeAuth ","Settings ")'">
  <img alt="Unlink Slack" height="30" width="30" style="padding-left:10px;" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/885554951857946624/sd7GRyjY_400x400.jpg" /><input class="slkInp" type="button" value="Unlink Slack" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("
    RevokeAuth ","Settings ")'"/></div>
<a href="https://slack.com/oauth/authorize?scope=identity.basic,identity.email,identity.team,identity.avatar&client_id=373568302675.374024189699">
  <img alt="Sign in with Slack" height="40" width="172" src="https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/sign_in_with_slack.png" srcset="https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/sign_in_with_slack.png 1x, https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/sign_in_with_slack@2x.png 2x"
  />
```

Comment: Can I just use HTML and not CSS for the above? Thank you so much this works, however, am looking at only doing it through HTML so instead of having a CSS file can I just add the attributes to the HTML? I am sorry I am really new to coding and not very well acquainted with terms etc. I am adding this code to a cshtml file and do not want to add a stylesheet.

Comment: I put the css into style tags and put it with the html this will not require an external css sheet.

Comment: Great. Awesome. Thank you so much.@Scath

Answer (score 1):

First off, I can't ask for clarification in a comment because of the 50 reputation requirement. Fair enough.

What it seems like you're asking is how do you want to style a button to look like the Slack button, but with only HTML? All they are doing here is using an `<img>` tag to throw a button on the screen. If you want to copy this behavior exactly, grab an image editor and draw a rounded rectangle with 1px black border, throw your icon on the right and some text on the left then follow the slack design:

```
<a href="https://linkhere.link">
  <img alt="Sign in with X" height="40" width="172" src="image.png" />
</a>
```

If you want to be able to have a button styled similarly with just HTML and CSS you can do that too, with your `input`:

```
input {
  height: 40px;
  width: 172px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  content: url(image.png);
  ...
}
```

Then add your own image and move the text and image to your liking.